# como sumar mas de dos valores dentro stream collecto group b

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, group-by, java-stream

**Tengo este metodo donde me retorna datos del cliente agrupados y tambien la suma de sus saldos pendientes**

**como se puede mostrar en el codigo de abajo estoy usando un Collectors.reducing para sumar los saldos pendientes, se puede seguir sumando en es misma linea?**

````
public List<EstadoCuentaVendedorDto> agruparCliente(List<EstadoCuentaVendedorDto> data){
        return data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> new TupleCliente(p.getNumeroDocumentoIdentidadCliente(),
                        p.getRazonSocialCliente(),
                        p.getNombreComercialCliente()
                ), Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO,
                        EstadoCuentaVendedorDto::getSaldoPendiente,
                        BigDecimal::add) ))

                .entrySet()
                .stream()

                .map(p -> new EstadoCuentaVendedorDto(p.getKey().getNumeroDocumentoIdentidadCliente(),
                                p.getKey().getRazonSocialCliente(),
                                p.getKey().getNombreComercialCliente(),
                                p.getValue().setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN)
                        )
                )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }```


**Ya que tengo esto dos campos mas que se necesitan sumar en ese mismo agrupado**

    ```private BigDecimal saldoPendienteMoroso;
    private BigDecimal saldoPendienteNoMoroso;```
````